# How to collect or store filtered out jsons in Spark filter function

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, hdfs, spark-streaming

i want to store or collect the filtered out data i.e the jsons which fail validations to hdfs or hbase.

```
dstream.filter { data => VitalValidator.isVitalJSONValid(data) }
```

where dstream is DStream[String] and **isVitalJSONValid** accepts string and returns boolean

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/help ?

Comment: briefly i had gone through, pls tell me whats wrong in this?

Comment: One code line is not enough. Please add more source code so the others can better be analiesed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this with Scala.

```scala
def isVitalJSONValid(data: String): Boolean = {
  var isValid = false

  //peroforms some validation 
  if(data.equals("some/validation")){
    isValid = true
  }
  !isValid
}


//existing goes on here
dstream.filter(data => isVitalJSONValid(data)).saveAsHadoopFiles("file_prefix")
```

[Output operations on dstreams](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams)

Comment: thanks for ur reply Srinivas, but your code collects the data only if the validations are true. moreover i want to process the valid data further and store/collect the invalid data into hbase or hdfs

Comment: here collect does not work, as it is Dstream[String]

Comment: pls check the edit. you can change `isVitalJSONValid` method as per your needs.